# How does Hangfire handle app domain restarts?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, backgroundworker, appdomain, hangfire

In my ASP.NET MVC application I'm going to be running background tasks, sometimes lasting ~10 minutes. I've read up on the subject and see that the app domain sometimes restarts thus removing my threads.

Therefore I've looked up some solutions. The primary solution I found is [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/). I understand that it restarts jobs when they fail etc., however do they "bypass" the app domain restart somehow or does it just restart the jobs in that case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The primary solution I found is Hangfire. I understand that it
>   restarts jobs when they fail etc., however do they "bypass" the app
>   domain restart somehow or does it just restart the jobs in that case?

No, they do not bypass app domain restarts - nothing can bypass it. Quote from the [documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/#job-storage):

> Hangfire keeps background jobs and other information that relates to
>   the processing inside a persistent storage. Persistence helps
>   background jobs to survive on application restarts, server reboots,
>   etc. This is the main distinction between performing background jobs
>   using CLR’s Thread Pool and Hangfire. Different storage backends are
>   supported.

So when you enqueue a new task, the first thing is to store it in some persistent storage on the server without keeping it in memory. This way if the app domain dies, the task can be read and resumed from this persistent storage later on.

Comment: I see. So am I right to assume that when the app domain restarts, the job will simply run again (from the beginning)?.

Comment: Yes, when the app domain starts again which might happen when the next request comes in. Or if you are using Hangfire as a separate Windows Service the task execution it won't even be interrupted by your ASP.NET app domain restarting.

Comment: Okay I see. Thanks for making it clear. I guess there's no silver bullet for my issue then (my job will fail if rerun at any point).

Comment: Yes it will fail if you keep some state in memory without persistence.